# Recover data from dead USB, lsblk shows it only for a few minutes

Tags: linux, usb, data-recovery

I am aware that there are many questions with this topic, but none have helped me.

The usb stopped working when the Mac it was connected to rebooted. Now macOS doesn't recognize it.

In Linux when connecting it nothing appears. lbslk does show it (sda drive) but only for a few minutes after plug in.

```
 hugo@linux:~$ lsblk -m
NAME          SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
loop0        29,9M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop1          55M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop2       255,6M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop3        62,1M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop4        49,8M root  disk  brw-rw----
sda         114,6G root  root  brw-------
nvme0n1     238,5G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─nvme0n1p1   260M root  disk  brw-rw----
├─nvme0n1p2    16M root  disk  brw-rw----
├─nvme0n1p3 215,3G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─nvme0n1p4   650M root  disk  brw-rw----
└─nvme0n1p5  22,3G root  disk  brw-rw----
```

with the rest of the commands (dd, testdisk) it doesn't let me do anything, the computer keeps thinking and after a few minutes it spits out an error.

```
hugo@linux:~$ sudo testdisk /dev/sda
TestDisk 7.1, Data Recovery Utility, July 2019
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
https://www.cgsecurity.org

Unable to open file or device /dev/sda: No such file or directory
```

Fdisk won't even show me

```
hugo@linux:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disco /dev/loop0: 29,9 MiB, 31334400 bytes, 61200 sectores
Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disco /dev/loop1: 54,98 MiB, 57626624 bytes, 112552 sectores
Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disco /dev/loop2: 255,58 MiB, 267980800 bytes, 523400 sectores
Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disco /dev/loop3: 62,9 MiB, 65105920 bytes, 127160 sectores
Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disco /dev/loop4: 49,8 MiB, 52203520 bytes, 101960 sectores
Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disco /dev/nvme0n1: 238,49 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectores
Disk model: WDC PC SN520 SDAPNUW-256G-1002          
Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tipo de etiqueta de disco: gpt
Identificador del disco: 91AC9595-4206-4C6C-B683-B3C6A41B5083

Dispositivo     Comienzo     Final  Sectores Tamaño Tipo
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    534527    532480   260M Sistema EFI
/dev/nvme0n1p2    534528    567295     32768    16M Reservado para Microsoft
/dev/nvme0n1p3    567296 452104846 451537551 215,3G Datos básicos de Microsoft
/dev/nvme0n1p4 498786304 500117503   1331200   650M Entorno de recuperación de Windows
/dev/nvme0n1p5 452106240 498786303  46680064  22,3G Sistema de ficheros de Linux

Las entradas de la tabla de particiones no están en el orden del disco.
```

Dmesg output

```
hugo@linux:~$ dmesg | tail
[ 4795.329863] usb usb1-port2: attempt power cycle
[ 4795.981808] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 112 using xhci_hcd
[ 4795.981940] usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 4796.189911] usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 4796.397781] usb 1-2: device not accepting address 112, error -71
[ 4796.525781] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 113 using xhci_hcd
[ 4796.525889] usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 4796.733883] usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 4796.941776] usb 1-2: device not accepting address 113, error -71
[ 4796.941819] usb usb1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Any tool or idea to recover data from usb?

Edit: I tried changing the permissions but same results.

Comment: Looks like it's dead. Time to recover from your backup. If no backup then search for a data recovery company. They can strip the chips to component level to try recover - you will, of course, be paying a lot of money for them to do that, with no guarantees.

Comment: As mentioned, it seems the USB controller is not working. My compliments on the thoroughness of your research and testing, though.